# Extracting variables from SpEL

Tags: java, spring, expression, spring-el

I need to know what all variables are there in an expression.

Consider the following code snippet,

```
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
EvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
context.setVariable("a", true);
context.setVariable("b", true);
context.setVariable("c", true);
boolean result = (Boolean) parser.parseExpression("#a AND (#b OR #c)").getValue(context);
```

Does SpEL have a functionality by which I can get all the variables that are there in my expression? Basically, I need something like this,

```
List<String> allVariables = parser.parseExpression("#a AND (#b OR #c)").getVariables();
// allVariables -> ["#a", "#b", "#c"]
```

My use case is that I am reading these expressions from a datastore and need to confirm if all the variables in the expression are valid.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a regex that extracts all the rules from the expression.

```
public List<String> extractRulesFromExpression(String ruleExpression) {
    List<String> listOfRules = new ArrayList<>();
    // This pattern extracts all string starting with "#" from the ruleExpression.
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-]*)[\\s]?|#([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-]*)$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ruleExpression);
    while (matcher.find()) {
      String rule = matcher.group().trim().substring(1);
      listOfRules.add(rule);
    }

    return listOfRules;
}
```

I know that this might not be an ideal solution or the thing I was exactly looking for, but it solves my use case.